# Error en evento Click de DataGridView en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un DataGridView con una columna donde tiene un boton para cada fila. Y para que se verifique que se toque el bonton, tengo la siguiente línea de código:

```
DataGridViewButtonCell cell = (DataGridViewButtonCell)DtgMovAgendados.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
```

El problema es que cuando se toca el Header (cualquier título de las columnas) me salta un error en este código.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que si se clickea en el header de las columnas, no haga nada o no me de ese error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo eso lo trabajo en el **evento CellClick** del **Datagridview** y pongo lo siguiente:

```
if(e.ColumnIndex == x && miDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   //código
}
```

Aquí lo que hago es que cuando de clic en la columna con índice x la cual sería mi botón y si además se cumple qué hay filas en el **Datagridview** entonces ejecuto el código. El número de columnas empieza en **0**, por lo que si querrías acceder por ejemplo al tercer índice de la columna sería **2**.

Comment: Hola Joel, podrías hacerme saber por favor si la respuesta te fue util

Comment: Recien pude conectarme. Voy a ponerme a hacerla hoy mismo y te respondo!

Comment: Lo he probado. Perdón la tardanza. Pero si funciona tal y como necesitaba. Gracias.

Comment: @JoelPallero hola, podrias marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvio, gracias